# Symfony CollectionType field with one default field

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-forms

I need your advice with CollectionType field.

I've made my collection type field using this: [Symfony CollectionType Field](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html)
Everything works fine. Even dynamic adding field with JQuery works properly.

But there is an issue.

I can't find out how to add one field each time the collection field renders. Right now after my page loads, my collection field is empty. However, I want the first field from the collection after every page load.

How to achieve this? Should I use Javascript or kind of form event? Any tips for finding a right chapter in documentation or code snippets will be very welcome.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? Are you trying to load an existing entity? Or do you just need a blank field on first load?

Comment: Ok. My CollectionType field option 'entry_type'   => TextType::class. So after page loads i want to see one text field ready to fill for user. I know that im passing array of fields but unfortunately I don't know how to add deafult first element.

Comment: It's been a while since I've done this - does `'allow_add' => true,` in the collection config not help?

Comment: According to documentation: "If allow_add is set to true, then if any unrecognized items are submitted, they'll be added seamlessly to the array of items." so it gives option to add dynamically field after submitting. However I want the first item rendered before submit right after page load.

Answer (score 2):

This way worked for me.

```
// 3 default values for empty form
$configArr = [[], [], []];

if ($builder->getData()) {
    $configArr = $builder->getData()->getColumns();
}

$builder->add('columns', CollectionType::class, [
    'entry_type' => ColumnType::class,
    'prototype' => true,
    'allow_add' => true,
    'allow_delete' => true,
    'data' => $configArr,
    'mapped' => false,
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I remember hitting this and I ended up creating data with an empty child on first load.

I'm unable to test this however I think the following should work depending on your form specifics.

```
public function someAction()
{
    $data = [];
    $data['collection_name'][] = ['text' => ''];

    $form = $this->createForm(SomeType::class, $data);

    return $this->templating->renderResponse('template.twig.html', [
        'form' => $form,
    ]);
}
```

Adding `'required' => false,` to the collection's form config should prevent empty items being persisted.

You may also investigate the configureOptions method on the form Type class:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $data = [];
    $data['collection_name'][] = ['text' => ''];
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'empty_data' => $data,
    ));
}
```

Comment: It doesn't resolve my problem. As I stated before I'm not using entities here. Just simple collection of text fields.

Comment: Ah ok - well the `$entity` I am passing in here can also be an array - if you add an empty array item for your collection into the `create` method, it will probably work the same.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not using entities with this approach. Once again: I have my form class with one field like: "$builder->add('texts', CollectionType::class, ['entry_type'   => TextType::class])". TextType is a standard symfony form field - not entity from database. When my page loads, collection(array) of this text fields is empty. I want this collection to have one text field by deafult everytime user loads form.

Comment: Yes - I appreciate you're not using entities, but you can pass an array with the empty items to the form create and it will map out empty collection types to match. I don't know what your structure looks like to suggest what that array looks like, but if you create a data array with an element for the name of your collection and an empty element in there, it will be rendered into the form.

Comment: Ok.So in which method or where in code i have to pass array with empty items? In controller I use createForm() method and you are using formFactory() in code above so I'm little confused.

Comment: I think I'm close to get it right. Let's suppose I want to add this not in the controller but in the form class. Is there a posibility of making it there?

Comment: Yes - I think so - see the end of my updated answer.

Comment: I think I'm gonna achieve this on the front-end side. I thought it could be easier at the server-side. Anyway thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

This simply worked for me.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $data = $builder->getData(); // data passed to the form
    $builder->add('textFields', CollectionType::class, [
        'entry_type' => TextType::class,
        'data' => $data ? $data->getTextFields() : ['']
    ]);
}
```